# Can we download DMol3 for free?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-mechanics

I want to try using DMol3 software for my research studies of doing optimisations and DFT calculations. Anyways I was unable to find a download link. Is it available for free? if so can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

[DMol3](https://www.3ds.com/fileadmin/PRODUCTS-SERVICES/BIOVIA/PDF/biovia-material-studio-dmol3.pdf) is part of the [Material Studio](https://www.3ds.com/products-services/biovia/products/molecular-modeling-simulation/biovia-materials-studio/) suite from BIOVIA. It is a commercially distributed software which means it is not free.

If you want to test it, you can ask for a trial period but, as I remember, the trial license does not permit that you publish any results obtained during the evaluation period.

A good news is that you can find plenty of free software that do the same things Dmol3 does. Take a look at the Wiki page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum_chemistry_and_solid-state_physics_software).